# Wake app when iOS device plugged in to power

Tags: ios

Is it possible to have an app in the background notified when an iOS device is plugged in to or unplugged from power?

Answer (score 1):

You need two functions:

```
CFRunLoopSourceRef IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource(IOPowerSourceCallbackType callback, void *context);
// to subscrive to a notification of a power source being changed
```

and

```
CFTypeRef IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo(void);
// to get info about your current power source
```

Both are described here: [IOPowerSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPowerSources_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011509)

I'm not sure is it going to work in background mode or not, but you can try.